# Помогите разобрать фрагмент

Tags: python, алгоритм

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в фрагменте кода?

По отдельности я знаю, что эти функции обозначают, а вот весь пазл тяжело собрать. В матрице нужно найти седловые точки (матрица типа `n*m`)

Сам код:

```
mx = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    [9, 17, 18, 19, 20]
]
    
sp = []

# Вот этот фрагмент не понятен:
for r, line in enumerate(mx):
    minimum = min(line)
    for c, element in enumerate(line):
        if element == minimum == max([line[c] for line in mx]):
            sp.append([r + 1, c + 1])
    
for s in sp:
    print(*s)
```

Comment: Алгоритм не самый эффективный. Функцию `max` можно вызывать намного реже. Сейчас сложность `nmm`, должна быть `nm`.

Answer (score 4):

Смотрите комментарии в коде:

```
# цикл по строкам матрицы
for r, line in enumerate(mx):
    # находим минимальное значение в строке с индексом `r` (row)
    minimum = min(line)
    #  цикл по значениям текущей строки (строка с индексом `r`)
    # т.е. по значениям всех столбцов в данной/текущей строке
    for c, element in enumerate(line):
        # если текущий (`c`-й) элемент строки равен минимальному в текущей строке
        # и одновременно равен максимальному значению в столбце `c`
        # тогда добавляем к результирующему списку элемент матрицы с
        # координатами [r + 1, c + 1]
        # NOTE: зачем к `r` и `c` добавляется единица - я не понял
        if element == minimum == max([line[c] for line in mx]):
            sp.append([r + 1, c + 1])
```

---

PS: похоже единица прибавляется только для того. чтобы перевести стандартную питоновскую индексацию (начинающуюся с нуля) в привычную человеческую, где первый элемент будет иметь индекс `1` вместо `0`.

Comment: Интересно , а есть алгоритм легче по нахождению седловых точек ?

Comment: @Alexander, думаю если использовать векторизированные методы Numpy/SciPy то получится короче и понятнее. Или вам нужно на чистом Python без использования доп. модулей?

Comment: Да мне нужно на чистом Python уже не знаю что делать все перебрал но не понятно , а нужно до завтра это провернуть

Comment: @Alexander, [есть](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40923408/9210255), так как эта программа ищет не все седловые точки.